# Roll-up summary : formula fields not showing in Field to agregate list

Tags: roll-up-summary

- I have a custom object `Opp__c` which is a Master of a child (Detail) object `Honorary__c`.
- `Honorary__c` holds currency values (Amounts) calculated differently depending on the Record Type.
- I need to store each amount (1 per Record Type) for analysis purposes.
- So I end up having 4 amounts : 1 Currency field and 3 Formula(Currency) fields.

I want to summary each of those amount fields in the `Opp__c` object.

The issue is that, in the Field to Aggregate list box, I can see several numeric/percent/Currency fields including the Currency field I need, but only 1 of the 3 formula(Currency) field I need.

Those Formula fields only use fields stored on the `Honorary__c` object (no cross-referencing). Calculations are performed using a currency and a percent field, like in the Formula field I can see in the list.

What might be the cause of this behavior ? If it is a normal behavior or due to a limitation, is there a workaround which doesn't use a Flow or Apex trigger ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you share what the formulas look like that you cannot select?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Sure :
- the one I can see : Nombre_de_jours__c * TJM__c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Thanks to Zack, I reviewed what the formula fields are made of, and I found that they finally are using 1 field which is a formula that DO use a cross formula field. So the first formula is the tree which hides the forest, and I had to climb up the chain and check every field used in the formula to find the reason of the issue.

Thank you for your help and sorry for the inconvenience